# Go (golang) Package consisting of several folders

Tags: file, go, package, directory

Is it possible in Go (golang) to have a package consisting of several .go files from different folders?

I am trying to make a subfolder inside of the main folder, and compiler says that it cannot find definitions ("undefined" error). When all the files are in the same folder, compilation does not give errors.

Thanks.

Comment: No. From [How to write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html): "Each package consists of one or more Go source files in a single directory.
"

Comment: That is sad. But thanks anyway! Can you post this answer as a separate answer, so that i can mark the question answered?

Comment: Well, of course you can, it just is not simple and requires invoking the Go compiler (not the go tool) by hand. You do not want to do this.

Comment: Why do you think this is sad? I know it is strange at the beginning, but packages are something you create lots of when writing go applications. So no need to have everything in one folder.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

If you want to use folders inside your go project you have to use several packages.

**NOT VALID**

```
myproject
| -- main.go (package main)
| -- routes.go (package main)
+ -- models
     | -- db.go (package main)
     | -- mymodel.go (package main)
```

**VALID**

```
myproject
| -- main.go (package main)
| -- routes.go (package main)
+ -- models
     | -- db.go (package models)
     | -- mymodel.go (package models)
```